# How to change value of a session bean from a request bean?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-1.2

I have a session bean `FooSessionBean` which has a boolean property: `visible`.

I want to change the value of the `visible` property from my FooRequestBean. Is there any way to do this, other than changing the scope of FooRequestBean to session instead of request (to be able to inject `FooSessionBean` into my `FooRequestBean`)?

Thanks in advance.

Ps: I'm using JSF 1.2

Comment: *other than changing the scope of FooRequestBean to session instead of request (to be able to inject FooSessionBean into my FooRequestBean)?* why do you think that it's not possible to inject a session scoped bean in a request scoped bean? It should work perfectly fine. What problems exactly are you encountering with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `FooSessionBean` property (getter/setter) in `FooRequestBean` and inject it using the `faces-config.xml`:

```
<managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name>fooRequestBeanName</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>foo.FooRequestBean</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
  <managed-property>
    <property-name>fooSessionBeanPropName</property-name>
    <property-class>foo.FooSessionBean</property-class>
    <value>#{sessionScope.fooSessionBeanName}</value> 
  </managed-property>
 //etc
```

Comment: Cool, it works:)... I thought that I cannot inject a session bean into a request one but only vice versa...

Comment: @Christian - you can inject from a wide scope into a narrower one; you just can't inject from a narrow scope into a wider one.